# "mix" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

tengo este error cuando intento correr el comando npm run watch, ya habia ejecutado antes el comando sin ningun problema pero por alguna razon surgio este problema, como puedo solucionarlo?

```
PS C:\laragon\www\LaravelVue> npm run watch

> @ watch C:\laragon\www\LaravelVue
> mix watch

"mix" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `mix watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-22T13_33_20_182Z-debug.log
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi packaje.json, creo que todo esta correcto en este archivo,no he modificado nada manualmente:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "element-ui": "^2.15.3",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.0.18",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2"
    }
}
```

y esto tengo en mi webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
 
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Lo instalaste y aún así no funciona? Primero tienes que instalar las dependencias `npm i` , luego corres `npm run watch`. Que versión estás usando? Como es el contenido de tus archivos package.json y webpack.mix.js?

Comment: ahi he modificado la pregunta, agregando lo que tengo en mi package.json y en mi webpack.mix.js

Comment: Prueba eliminando el directorio `node_modules` y el archivo `package-lock.json`, luego vuelve a instalar las dependencias con `npm i`, y finalmente `npm run watch`.

Comment: simplemente los elimino desde el navegador del vscode y ejecuto el npm i?

Comment: Sí, puedes borrarlos desde el IDE, el administrador de archivos del sistema operativo o desde la consola